# Unexpected Weierstrass $\wp$-Function Behavior

Tags: numerics, special-functions

In *Mathematica*, the Weierstrass $\wp$-function is expressed by

```
 WeierstrassP[u + I v, {g₂, g₃}]
```

where `g₂` and `g₃` are the invariants and *Mathematica* can convert the two half-periods $\omega_1$ and $\omega_3$ to the invariants using the code

```
 WeierstrassInvariants[{ω₁, ω₃}]
```

Analytically, we should have $\wp(u + 2M\omega_1 + 2N\omega_3) = \wp(u)$,
where $M$ and $N$ are integers.  However, I'm seeing really, really confusing things in *Mathematica*:

Let's take $\omega_{1}=0.01$ and $\omega_{3} = \frac{1}{2}i$.  We compute the invariants as:

```
WeierstrassInvariants[{0.01, 0.5 I}]
```

> ```
> {8.11742*^8, 4.45088*^12}
> ```

Let's evaluate this function at 2.01 on real line:

```
WeierstrassP[2.01, {8.11742*10^8, 4.45088*10^12}]
```

> ```
> 16449.3
> ```

Since one of our half-periods is $\omega_{3} = \frac{1}{2} i$, we should get the exact same number by adding $i$ to the argument.  But we get something horribly different!

```
WeierstrassP[2.01 + I, {8.11742*10^8, 4.45088*10^12}]
```

> ```
> -8078.31 + 0.0011423 I
> ```

This seems like such a simple thing and it's been frustrating me for a while now.  Does anyone have any idea what's going on here?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't use machine precision arguments, for one. Second, see what *WeierstrassHalfPeriods* on the invariants tells you...

Comment: What do you mean by machine precision arguments?

Comment: Well, you do realize that you are evaluating near the poles, yes? It is also apparent that your period parallelogram is quite skinny, due to your choice of periods. Why not use arbitrary precision for your computations? (Replace `0.01` with `1/100` and `0.5 I` with `I/2`, redo with `N[number, precision]`, and report back.)

Comment: Will do, thanks.  I get strange behavior even away from the poles.  I've been plotting the function $Abs[\wp(u) - \wp(2w_{1} - u)]$ for $u$ real between zero and the half-period $w_{1}$.  Analytically, this function should identically vanish but I've got some really rich plots which converge to a parabolic shape as $w_{1}$ goes to zero.  Could this really be caused by machine precision issues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say your problems are definitely caused by using machine precision arithmetic. Let's look at your computation with more tractable invariants.

Machine precision computing

```
invar1 = WeierstrassInvariants[{.2, .5 I}] // Chop
```

> ```
> {5073.57, 69539.7}
> ```

```
WeierstrassP[2.01, invar1]
```

> ```
> 10000. + 0. I
> ```

```
WeierstrassP[2.01 + 2. I, invar1]
```

> ```
> 10000. - 6.16394*10^-7 I
> ```

Although the two results are recognizably close, there is some wandering off the real line in the second case.

Controlled precision computing

```
 invar2 = WeierstrassInvariants[{2/10, I/2}]
 N[WeierstrassP[2 + 1/100, invar2], 20]
```

> ```
> 10000.025392725332489
> ```

```
 N[WeierstrassP[2 + 1/100 + I, invar2], 20]
```

> ```
> 10000.0253927253324887 + 0.*10^-17 I
> ```

This clearly does much better than using machine precision.

Comment: Thank you.  Can you implement this N[ , ] command within plots?

Comment: @spietro. I'm reluctant to say that you can use it anywhere, but I can't think  of anywhere where you can't use it. Advise you to read the documentation on `N` and `Precision`.

Comment: @spietro, with respect to plots, you may want to adjust the setting of `WorkingPrecision` for good accuracy.

Comment: @m_goldberg Thanks.  I'll play around with it.  I'm still baffled that I got such nice, symmetric plots if it was all just precision error.  Not only symmetry, but nice patterns emerged as I decreased the periods.

Comment: @spietro. Numerics is an art not a science :-)

Comment: Elliptic functions such as yours are usually implemented with methods like period reduction. As I said earlier, @spietro, you are evaluating near the poles, so after the period reduction, you end up with much subtractive cancellation, and your now not-so-accurate reduced argument will now yield not-so-accurate results. Here's an idea: why not use the homogeneity relations to ease the numerics? Those relations are listed in Abramowitz and Stegun, or at the DLMF.

Comment: The situation is similar to the trigonometric functions: it is well-known that evaluating them for large arguments often yields results not as accurate as one would like, due to cancellation during period reduction.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. When I use "WorkingPrecision" all my plots disappear.  Not go to zero, like they should, but disappear altogether.  Is there a subtlety in applying this?  I can't find anything in the documentation.

Comment: @spietro, how high a setting did you use in `Plot[]` (or whatever plotting function you're using)? Did you use the exact form `WeierstrassP[z, WeierstrassInvariants[{1/100, I/2}]]`?

Comment: @Guesswhoitis, yes, I used that exact form and I used WorkingPrecision-->60

Comment: Try going higher, @spietro…

Comment: @Guesswhoitis, still didn't work.  I'm trying to plot: `Plot3D[Abs[-WeierstrassP[x1 + I*(1 - e), inv] + 
   WeierstrassP[(200 - x1) + I*(1 - e), inv]], {x1, 0, 200}, {e, 0, 
  9/100}, WorkingPrecision -> 100] ` and it's still just giving a blank plot.